# Spring+Hibernate+MySQL CRUD not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, crud

I wanted to learn how to make a simple `Spring`+`Hibernate`+`MySQL` CRUD.

I found a  [tutorial](http://javawebtutor.com/articles/spring/spring-mvc-hibernate-crud-example.php). I wanted to run it on my PC first(to check if it's working and then learn what particular lines do). I downloaded the zip file and changed couple of things like name of the package or name of the database, the `Spring/Hibernate` version and so on.

Unfortunately the program is not working.
Of course there is a possibility that the tutorial is somewhere wrong but I bet that it's me not the tutorial that screwed something up.

If anybody have some free time I will really appreciate any help :)

This is a [link](https://github.com/Reastohr/EmployeeManager) to a github repo where I put code.

I use `Eclipse` and `Tomcat 9`.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post your error stack! Let us know where exactly your problem is.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I post my console log or something like that? :)

Comment: Yes! Whatever error stack you are getting in your console. Check other questions to get an idea.

Comment: When I will come back home I will post my error stack  :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot easier way to get started with Spring completly from a scratch.

It's called Spring Boot and it is composed of an embedded servlet engine (Tomcat) and takes care of configuration of almost everything.

It doesn't require XML configuration which is a blessing and makes you feel like 2017, not 2000.

I found this video tutorial a very useful one and I can recommend it to you:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgPkUVF862g

Also, this series of video tutorials is excellent and explains everything about Spring MVC and Spring Boot, but it seems that first video is missing..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3ZrOj4unss

Comment: I'm not sure if that was a sarcastic comment or not but nevertheless after seeing what is this video about I think that firstly I will learn strong Spring basics and then I will try to mix that with some database stuff :) Thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: You're welcome, I added another link to a video that describes how Spring MVC works with an example in Spring Boot

Comment: Dziekuje bardzo :D